# Removing double spacing within a string of alphanumerical values KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split, strip

I'm trying to remove double spacing and replace it with a single space within DataFrame header names
But when I do so it messes with the header.
As the end of each line is a double space it replace that with single space too and then the DataFrame looks weird. How would I replace ONLY double spaces within a string of alphanumerical values?

`raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index") KeyError: "['HEADER NAME'] not in index"`

`csv_data.columns = [x.strip().replace('  ', ' ') for x in csv_data.columns]`

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it, you just need to add the double space back at the end of every row:

```
csv_data.columns = [x.strip().replace('  ', ' ') + "  " for x 
in csv_data.columns]
```